# Can I have a radio button group with only one radio button, and have it still function as a radio button group?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, radio-button, radio-group

I have an input form that uses radio buttons arranged in radio button groups. My question is: “Can I have a radio button group with only one radio button, and have it still function as a radio button group?”

I know this may sound silly. Why use a radio button group if only one button? But I am not being difficult or making up a theoretical case. In my application code, the radio button group is dynamically generated via javascript, and is placed within a scrolling div (not shown). Suppose the radio button group is for race, and there are four buttons: white, black, hispanic, other. User deletes three of the categories, and is left with hispanic, for example. Suffice it to say I have a genuine need to (at times) have one radio button in the group.

Please do not make the understandable suggestion to use a select box or check box. I specifically need to use radio buttons to look and function much better (for this data analysis application) on mobile devices.

I believe the following source code illustrates the problem. In Case 1, the DOM thinks the radio button group is `HTMLInputElement`. In case 2, it is considered to be `RadioNodeList` (normal radio button group). Case 3 uses dummy hidden button as possible workaround, DOM considers single visible button to be `RadioNodeList` object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function showInfo (case_num) {
  var groupName = "group" + case_num;
  var objectVar = myForm.elements.namedItem (groupName);
  var str = '';
  str += "Case number: " + case_num;
  str += "\nobjectVar = " + objectVar;
  str += "\nobjectVar.value = " + objectVar.value;
  str += "\nobjectVar.name = " + objectVar.name;
  str += "\nobjectVar.length = " + objectVar.length;
  str += "\nobjectVar.checked = " + objectVar.checked;
  str += "\nobjectVar[0] = " + objectVar[0];
  str += "\nobjectVar[1] = " + objectVar[1];
  if (objectVar[0] != undefined) {
    str += "\nobjectVar[0].value = " + objectVar[0].value;
    str += "\nobjectVar[0].name = " + objectVar[0].name;
    str += "\nobjectVar[0].checked = " + objectVar[0].checked;
    }
  if (objectVar[1] != undefined) {
    str += "\nobjectVar[1].value = " + objectVar[1].value;
    str += "\nobjectVar[1].name = " + objectVar[1].name;
    str += "\nobjectVar[1].checked = " + objectVar[1].checked;
    }
  alert (str);
  }
</script>
<form name="myForm" action="">
Case 1: Single radio button in "group1" group:
<br>
<input type="radio" id="m1" name="group1" value="m1" onchange="showInfo (1);">
<label for="m1">M</label>
<br>
<br>
Case 2: Two radio buttons in "group2" group:
<br>
<input type="radio" id="m2" name="group2" value="m2" onchange="showInfo (2);">
<label for="m2">M</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="f2" name="group2" value="f2" onchange="showInfo (2);">
<label for="f2">F</label>
<br>
<br>
Case 3: Single visible radio button in "group3" group, with hidden button:
<br>
<input type="radio" id="m3" name="group3" value="m3" onchange="showInfo (3);">
<label for="m3">M</label>
<input style="display: none;" type="radio" id="f3" name="group3" value="f3" onchange="showInfo (3);">
<label style="display: none;" for="f3">F</label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Since the DOM switches the object type, that complicates things. For example, `RadioNodeList` has a length property, `HTMLInputElement` does not. More fundamentally, the type is still radio, so why not still a radio button group with one node? I know I can figure out which object type by looking at the properties and going from there as a workaround. However, I would prefer that it remain a `RadioNodeList` even if just one radio button. Is that possible?

[Added after getting comment] Hiding or disabling buttons will not work, because the categories (eg, race groups) can be combined into "sets". For example, "white" could be combined with "other" for a new set "white / other". Each time the user carries out an action, the program needs to generate a new radio button group with the current categories and sets. Now, it is possible to have a dummy button hidden, to fool the program into thinking always GT 1 button. The dummy hidden button does work, I added to the example after getting comment, seems kludgy, but is a workaround, perhaps about the same as testing for the object type.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#radio-button-state-typeradio says “A document must not contain an input element whose radio button group contains only that element.” I am not sure what that means exactly, but perhaps it is saying cannot have just one radio button in group. If so, they sure have an obscure way of saying it.  Anybody know situation with one radio button in group?

My best guess, when only one radio button, no longer considered a radio button group. Can someone verify this, provide suggestions / reasoning, or correct anything I might have gotten confused? Thanks

Comment: Could you hide the unneeded radio buttons?  ie, set style.display="none" for the button and its label - or, perhaps, wrap them in a div and hide that so that you include the br tag as well.

Comment: It is a reasonable suggestion, thanks, but hide will not work, because the categories (eg, race groups) can be combined into "sets". For example, "white" could be combined with "other" for a new set "white / other". Each time the user carries out an action, the program generates new radio button group, and also keeps track using javascript arrays and hidden variables (for sending to cgi server). This means that my other suggested alternative, to disable radio button for a deleted category, does not work, and so I edited my post.

Comment: So, are you thinking of a radio-button version of cascading select lists?  ie, if I select one value from List A, List B is changed to only show items relating to the selection in List A.

Comment: Not cascading select lists. Instead, a single list, such as "race sets". User actions include delete a set, add a set, combine sets into a new set. Basically make any combination. After user action, AJAX gets data from server, client javascript updates radio buttons, using innerHTML into <div> tag. It all works, I am just switching from <select> tag, which looks awful and performs poorly on smartphone for this situation, and ran into the business with one radio button maybe not being a radio group.

Comment: Your initial code seems to have been changed.  Anyway, how does the user add/delete anything from anywhere as there is no button or input boxes for them?

Comment: Yes, I improved the example to add Case 3 with the dummy hidden radio button. Any problem with that? I never suggested the example code does any add/delete. Instead, as stated, the example code shows the problem I ran into. Thanks for responding and trying to help. But could someone please address the question I asked: Can I have a radio button group with only one radio button, and have it still function as a radio button group? Thank you

Comment: Your initial post said "User deletes three of the categories, and is left with hispanic..." and your previous comment included a "user action" of "add a set".  Your question and code example should have just shown a single radio button in a group and asked if this is possible. A radio group can have one button, but it will no longer act as a group - the functionality of a radio group is that selecting one radio button deselects all others in the group.  A single radio button only gives you the option of leaving it deselected or selecting it permanently as there is no means of deselecting it.

Comment: I said "In my application code" related to add/delete, never suggested the example did add/delete. And my code example *did* show a single radio button in a group, that was the whole point. And I already know a single radio button cannot be deselected, I don't want it to be deselected. I appreciate your trying, but you are not being helpful. Could someone please address my actual question?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps nobody understood the question. Anyway, here is the answer, to my best understanding.

In terms of what the user sees, the answer is "yes, I can have a radio button group with only one button, and have it still function as a radio button group". You can see in the example: There is just one radio button. It starts unchecked. The user can check it. Once checked, it cannot be unchecked. No big deal. But there it is.

In terms of what the programmer sees, the answer is "no, a single radio button does not function as a radio button group, is a different object, but it can be dealt with". As shown in the example, a radio button group with only one button is `HTMLInputElement` object. With more than one button, it is `RadioNodeList` object.

Why the experts made this decision (`HTMLInputElement` if only one button) is beyond me. To me, it would be like my math teacher saying I could not have a set with a single element. But perhaps I am missing something. Anyway, there it is, those are the facts.

How are `RadioNodeList` and `HTMLInputElement` (the two cases) similar or different to the programmer? Keep in mind that the interface may change so that what started as several radio buttons ends as one. If the code does not take that into account, it will fail, since the objects are different.

Both objects have `value` property - No matter whether one or more than one radio box, `value` property gives string telling which box is checked. For either case, it is the value of the checked box, or empty string if no box checked. So I believe this works the same for either case.

Only `RadioNodeList` has `length` property. So if you do not test, the code will eventually crash. The test `if (my_object.length === undefined)` evaluates to false if `RadioNodeList` object and true for `HTMLInputElement` object (length is essentially one in that case).

Only `HTMLInputElement` has `name` property, but individual nodes of `RadioNodeList` also have `name` property, and share the same name, required for a radio button group. In either case, when the form is submitted, I believe it works the same, but I have not directly tested this.

Only `RadioNodeList` has a collection of nodes that you can iterate over, with `NodeList.forEach()` syntax or with `for loop` and `NodeList[ndx]` syntax. Try to do this with `HTMLInputElement` and the code will crash. If `length` property exists, you can iterate, otherwise just one `HTMLInputElement` element.

I think the best way to appreciate the differences is to look at the output from the example code, which I have further edited to add some more details. Please add any other comments if you wish, but I am not expecting anything. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="uk-heading-line uk-text-center uk-text-baseline uk-h2"><span class="uk-link-heading uk-margin-top uk-link-reset">Radio button group</span></p>

<form id="form" class="uk-padding uk-width-1-1" onsubmit="return false;">
  <div>
    <label class=" uk-text-light uk-text-muted">Label1</label>
    <div id="button-group1" class=" uk-button-group uk-width-1-1 uk-margin-small-top" uk-switcher>
      <label class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-large uk-width-1-3 "><input type="radio" hidden />radio1</label>
      <label class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-large uk-width-1-3 "><input type="radio" hidden />radio2</label>
      <label class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-large uk-width-1-3 "><input type="radio" hidden />radio3</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="uk-margin-top">
    <label class=" uk-text-light uk-text-muted">Label2</label>
    <div class="uk-button-group uk-width-1-1 uk-margin-small-top" uk-switcher>
      <label class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-large uk-width-1-4"><input type="radio" hidden />radio4</label> 
      <label class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-large uk-width-1-4"><input type="radio" hidden />radio5</label>
      <label class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-large uk-width-1-4"><input type="radio" hidden />radio6</label>
      <label class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-large uk-width-1-4"><input type="radio" hidden />radio7</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).